# SFTP giving all permissions to a user

Tags: ssh, sftp

How can I give all permissions to a SFTP user? I mean to have acess to all folders, delete and upload as they want.(I'm on ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's not such thing as a *SFTP user*, there are users that can access the system on the console, or over ssh or over ftp, etc. Those users, once authenticated, can possibly run some application like a shell, or the sftp subsystem of ssh, but the processes they run will still be constrained by the system access controls.

There is one user that is not constrained by access control restriction: the all-powerful `root` user. That's the user you generally want to impersonate when running administrative tasks. That can be using `sudo` for instance, but you can also authenticate as that user over `ssh`.

As that user is all-powerful, care is taken that authentication is performed in a safe manner. When it comes to access over ssh, by default, password authentication which is not very safe is not allowed. You'd use key authentication instead.

To be able to `sftp` as `root` (`sftp root@user:/path`), you'd add your public ssh key as a new line in the `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. You could also restrict the ssh authentication with that key to be used for sftp only with:

```
restrict,command="internal-sftp" your-public-key-here
```

(not that it would restrict what can be done on that system with that public key; if you can modify any file on the system, you can have the system do anything)

If you really wanted to authenticate as you, but like root, not being subject to any restriction when using the SFTP subsystem, it should still be possible using Linux capabilities.

For instance, doing:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

To divert the original `sftp` to `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server.distrib`.

```
sudo install -m 0110 -g yourusername /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server.{distrib,unrestricted}
```

To make a copy executable only by `yourusername`.

```
sudo setcap 'cap_dac_override+ep cap_chown+ep cap_fowner+ep cap_fsetid+ep' /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server.unrestricted
```

Setting capabilities for that one executable to remove all restrictions when it comes to filesystem access.

And then create `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` as a script such as:

```
#! /bin/bash -
if [ "$LOGNAME" = yourusername ]; then
  cmd=$0.unrestricted
else
  cmd=$0.distrib
fi
exec -a "$0" -- "$cmd" "$@"
```

(don't forget to make it executable with `sudo chmod a+x /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`).

Then, when you use the sftp service (typically over ssh), you'll have no restriction.

But beware your retain your identity. For instance, if you upload a new file, by default, it will be owned by you. It's bad practice to have system files owned by regular users.

Comment: @zevzek, not much, if you can modify any file, you can do anything.